# Pan Card Validation in Android

Tags: android, validation

I have to do validation like this how to achieve it .

Should contain exactly 5 letters in Large Caps followed by exactly 4 digits followed by 1 letter in Large Caps (Example - KLMNO5661P)

Answer (score 6):

You can use RegEX (Regular Expression) to check the format

```
String s = "ABCDE1234F"; // get your editext value here
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
// Check if pattern matches 
if (matcher.matches()) {
  Log.i("Matching","Yes");
}   

[A-Z]{5} - match five literals which can be A to Z
[0-9]{4} - followed by 4 numbers 0 to 9
[A-Z]{1} - followed by one literal which can A to Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final String pan_pattern = "(([A-Za-z]{5})([0-9]{4})([a-zA-Z]))";

checkpan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pan_pattern);
        if (!regex_matcher(r, pan_number.getText().toString())) {
            error = "Invalid PAN number";
        }
    }
});
```

**regex_matcher**

```
private boolean regex_matcher(Pattern pattern, String string) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);
    return m.find() && (m.group(0) != null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using kotlin PAN card valudation:-

```
fun checkPancardValidation(panCard: String): Boolean {
    val pattern: Pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}")
    val matcher: Matcher = pattern.matcher(panCard)
    return matcher.matches()
}



 if (et_pan_card.text.isNullOrEmpty() || !checkPancardValidation(et_pan_card.text.toString())) {
        et_pan_card.error = "It should contain upper case letter and number only"
        return false
    }
```